# Uppercase to lowercase

Tags: magento2

I have capitalized all my products title, is there a way to convert all products to lowercase?
Is there a way to do it without an extension?

Comment: Where you want to do this one?

Comment: in the title of the products

Comment: Means are you want to show into the frontend PDP page? In the admin, actually how you added the name of the product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can update the product titles to lowercase without using an extension by following these steps:

1.**Backup your database:** Before making any changes to the database, it is important to create a backup.

2.Run the update query: You can update the product titles to lowercase by running the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = LOWER(value) WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = 4);
```

3.Run the basic CLI commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then check the output.

**Please note that this will update all the product titles to lowercase and there is no way to undo the changes once they are made. Therefore, always try with backup and execute first in your test environment.**